# How to interprete a generic uml class definition

Tags: java, generics

How to implement `MyClass` based on the UML below? If I strictly follow the UML I would implement this:

```
public class MyClass implements MyInterface<String>{
    private ArrayList<List<T>>myMemberVar;

    public String methode(String t){
        //do something
        return "";
    }
}
```

But I think a more practical solution would be this:

```
public class MyClass implements MyInterface<String>{
    private ArrayList<List<String>>myMemberVar;

    public String methode(String t){
        //do something
        return "";
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think the variable should be:

```
private List<String> myMemberVar;
```

Comment: you are right I forget the access modifier for my member, but my question is about the generic pattern.